# Как сделать плавное перемещение предмета за камерой в ue4 c++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine-4

Как сделать так чтобы, предмет, оружие или фонарик в руках FirstPersonCharacter перемещались, с задержкой. Понимаете? Я просто не знаю как это правильно объяснить. Сразу извиняюсь за пример, который я сейчас напишу, просто другой не могу вспомнить. Есть игра Granny Chapter 2, там, когда вы подбираете предмет и двигаете камерой, то этот предмет запаздывает за этим движением, как будто плавно перемещается. Вот видео фрагмент:

https://youtu.be/TQwiRapQyFs

Как сделать, чтобы предмет в руках персонажа двигался также с запозданием как и на видео? Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Я новичок в UE4.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я добавил ссылку с примером того что мне нужно сделать, как-то так.